# "ls" not working on Ubuntu 10.04

Tags: environment-variables, paths, ls

All of the sudden the handy command `ls` stopped working on my Ubuntu 10.04 server.

The only thing I did was add a new entry to the PATH environment variable and that was all.

Here is the result from `echo $PATH`:

```
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/root/java/bin
```

Why this is happening?

Also, I navigated to the `/usr/bin` folder and the `ls` program was there but I wasn't able to run it from there either.

Edit: 'ps' is also not working.
I also tried to remove the lines I edited on .bashrc and nothing changes

Plus `stat /bin/ls` gives me this:

```
Size: 39696         Blocks: 80         IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 802h/2050d  Inode: 13377592    Links: 1
Access: (0755/-rwxr-xr-x)  Uid: (  122/ UNKNOWN)   Gid: (  114/ UNKNOWN)
Access: 2011-08-11 06:25:04.000000000 +0200
Modify: 2010-09-21 20:32:55.000000000 +0200
Change: 2011-07-24 17:22:39.000000000 +0200
```

Comment: Could you please include in your question exactly what happens when you run `ls`.

Comment: @N.N. From the way I'm reading it, it does nothing.

Comment: `ls` is typically in `/bin/ls`

Comment: -bash: /bin/ls: No such file or directory

Comment: You did see a `ls` in `/usr/bin` ? That's odd, there shouldn't be one, it should only be in `/bin` as Marco said. What does `ls -l /usr/bin/ls` say? Does running `/bin/ls` directly work?

Comment: Nope, it doesn't works :S, and, my mistake, ls is in the /bin folder, not /usr/bin

Comment: I suggest to remove your modified lines from `~/.bashrc` or wherever they are. If you're unsure, copy them from `/etc/skel`, then restart your session.

Comment: see if this helps- `PATH=/bin;ls` If that works, then there is something wrong with your current PATH variable.

Comment: Do `which ls` and `echo /bin/* | grep ls$` show `/bin/ls`?

Comment: Is `ls` the only command that doesn't work?

Comment: @Shoan yep, ls is the only command that doesn't works :/

Comment: @user606723 Tried that, no success :(

Comment: @enzotib I've tried that, no succes! Man, I'm running out of ideas to solve this...

Comment: Errata: ps is also not working

Comment: What does `stat /bin/ls` tell you?

Comment: Can you update the question with your findings based on the comments here? This would make it easier to understand the question without having to traverse this discussion.

Comment: If `/bin/ls` does not work then all this has definitely nothing to do with your PATH variable... A hardware defect of the harddisk where the root file system resides seems to be more likely.

Comment: Do you have enhanced security features enabled such as [AppArmor](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/AppArmor) ?

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the file size and [this link](http://forums.cpanel.net/f5/rootkit-shv4-server-compromised-28771.html), you have a rootkit on your system. The most sensible course of action is to make a backup of any personal data and reinstall from scratch.